# Reading xls in OptaPlanner

Tags: apache-poi, optaplanner

i am facing problems reading xls having complex formulas in OptaPlanner, using Apache POI.

Is there any known limitations? Please suggest the resolution steps

Comment: "Please suggest the resolution steps": Steps for solving what? Please tell the exact problems you are facing.

Comment: Reading cells with absolute values is easy. If there is any formula in the cell (even a reference to a cell in another tab, for example), an error is thrown!

Comment: What code throws what error? That your debugging has pointed to formulas as the reason also is important information which should be mentioned in the question. So what code throws what error having what formula in what kind of `Excel` file (`*.xls` or `*.xlsx`)?